# Is there any benefit to returning the result of assigning a value to a local variable rather than the value directly?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am doing a java code inspection.  Here is a function (snippet):

```
String getValue() {
     String res;
     StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

     // More code here that sets strBuilder

     return res = strBuilder.toString();
}
```

First there is a warning that the value of res is not used.  Secondly I don't understand the return.  Why don't they just `return( strBuilder.toString() )`.  Is there some sort of advantage?

Comment: Since `res` is not used you are right, there is no reason to return like that. Just `return bs.toString()` is ok.

Comment: String getValue() should be listed as part of the code but I can't get the format to work.  Sorry.

Comment: No. The `res` variable could be safely removed.

Comment: This will not only return a `String`, but it will first assign it to a `String`.  I can't see any advantage to this.

Answer (score 12):

`res` is not used, so there is no reason to return like that. You can remove it:

```
String getValue() {
     StringBuilder bs = new StringBuilder();
     //
     // More code here that sets sb

     return bs.toString();
}
```

Comment: Any theories as to why it would have been written that way in the first place?

Comment: My guess is that someone replaced a lot of string appends to 'res' with a string builder for optimization, but didn't quite finish the job.

Comment: @MartinSmith To be honest, I don't know... Alan's theory is good, but who knows what the developer was thinking of when he/she was writing this code? :)

Comment: @MartinSmith, I don't know about Java debuggers, but in the C++ debuggers I'm familiar with, that construct would let you set a watchpoint on `res` so you could inspect the value of `bs.toString()` just before the return.

Comment: @Mark Java debuggers would be able to look inside the StringBuilder, so that isn't a (valid) reason.

Answer (score 10):

That sort of code can sometimes result from incomplete removal of debug artifacts:

```
String getValue() {

     String res;
     StringBuilder bs = new StringBuilder();
     //
     // More code here that sets sb

     res = bs.toString();
     // Test and/or display res here
     return res; 
}
```

It certainly seems like a good candidate for the next round of refactoring and clean-up.

Answer (score 6):

Just guessing, but some (most?) IDEs don't allow you to directly inspect the value of function returns. With this scheme, you could put a breakpoint at the end of the method, and mouse over "res" to get the return value.

Comment: Being able to inspect values is I why I often use the `var res = calculation; return res;` style. I hope the optimizer (of any language) will generate the same code for `var res = calculation; return res;` vs. `return calculation;`.

Comment: After writing the comment, I realised that at least for (pre move semantics) C++, having the assignment and return cost no cycles required some care for the writer of the class's copy constructors and assignment operators.  This might also occur in Java for other classes than string.

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely right; assignment to `res` makes no sense; `return bs.toString();` would do the the same.

---

P.S. **+1 for not ignoring compiler warnings**.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do either

```
String res = strBuilder.toString();
return res ;
```

Or directly,

```
return strBuilder.toString();
```

Now If you want to know about benefits as you asked `Is there any benefit`, i always prefer directly return. My personal logic is simple as

- You gonna write one line less code !!!  (declaring variables allover is not a good feeling to me and also you don't have to think about the name of the variable, conflicts etc.. those silly matter )
- The value will not be stored in memory and wait for the `GC` to collect it. SO, less memory see.....
- Fast write to a variable and then read from it and return ..... more read/write isn't it?

**Those things are nothing big, I had to say as you asked**

Answer (score -4):

Can also be written as:

```
String getValue() {
    return new StringBuilder().toString();
}
```

Comment: I think that `// More code here that sets sb` Meant something like `I'm not writing the entire code here, but note that 'bs' is used in this method, and does have a value at the end of it`

Comment: You could just `return "";` as well, but that's clearly not the point.